# python join single characters in string

Tags: python, join, split

Input:

```
str1 = "a b abcd a b"
```

Desired output:

```
"ab abcd ab"
```

How do I remove the white space in between single characters of the string only?

I guess I can not use split and join as it will tokenize all and then would not care about the length of the substrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `re.sub`.  We can match on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\b[a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)
```

and then replace with empty string, to remove the targeted space.

```
input = "a b abcd a b"
output = re.sub(r'(?<=\b[a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)', '', input)
print(output)

ab abcd ab
```

The regex pattern used says to:

```
(?<=\b[a-z])   assert that what precedes is a single letter, which itself
               is preceded by a word boundary
[ ]            match a single space (brackets used for clarity only)
(?=[a-z]\b)    assert that what follows is also a single letter, which again
               is followed by a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also think of it the other way round: pad the long strings

```
def padLong(item):
    if len(item) == 1:
        return item
    return ' ' + item + ' '

str1 = "a b abcd a b abc abcd"

strs = str1.split()
print(strs)

strs = ''.join([padLong(item) for item in strs])
print(strs)

strs = strs.split()
strs = ' '.join(strs)
print(strs)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'abcd', 'a', 'b', 'abc', 'abcd']
ab abcd ab abc  abcd 
ab abcd ab abc abcd
```